# array getting indexed want single key

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

> I have an array which is getting indexed and then storing the values and every time $aba changes it stores ithe values in a new index of arrray $abc[]
>    .what i want is to get an array in a single dimension   not geting getting nested
>     **My Array**

```
array (size=3)
   0 => //get rid of this
       array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[29]
        public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
        public 'fname' => string 'Tester 1' (length=8)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[30]
        public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
        public 'fname' => string 'Tester 2' (length=8)
  1 => //get rid of this
     array (size=1)
       0 => 
         object(stdClass)[32]
           public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
        public 'fname' => string 'Tester 3' (length=8)
```

**My Code**

$aba= explode('/-', $this->session->userdata('area')); //grabs session data

```
for($i=1;$i<count($aba);$i++)

  {
          echo $aba[$i];
        $abc[]=$this->db->where('area', $aba[$i])->get('student')->result();

     }  

 var_dump($abc);
```

> I Want the array to be like this

```
 0 => 
            object(stdClass)[29]
            public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
            public 'fname' => string 'Tester 1' (length=8)
 1 => 
            object(stdClass)[30]
            public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
            public 'fname' => string 'Tester 2' (length=8)
  2 => 
                object(stdClass)[30]
                public 'id' => string '11' (length=2)
                public 'fname' => string 'Tester 3' (length=8)
```

Comment: **It Is getting indexed like that because of $abc[] in my for loop   and i cant just use $abc as it will keep replacing values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i thought it is assigning an array at each key because your query is returning an array. If you want a single array then you can use -

```
$result = $this->db->where('area', $aba[$i])->get('student')->result();
$abc = array_merge($abc, $result);
```

It will provide you a single array.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit answer is a little more clear as he defined the array.. but i upped your post too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$newArr = array();
for($i=1;$i<count($aba);$i++)

  {
      $abc = $this->db->where('area', $aba[$i])->get('student')->result();
      // merge new values into the array instead of adding new keys
      $newArr = array_merge($newArr, $abc)
 }  

 var_dump($newArr); //this should be required array
```